# Angular UI Modal not appearing after grunt build

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am using angular ui bootstrap for my project. The modal is working fine but when i buid using the grunt build command, the modal stops appearing. Can anyone help me in this. I already have got the similar question [angular-ui-bootstrap causes unknown provider error when minified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553974/angular-ui-bootstrap-causes-unknown-provider-error-when-minified) but no satisfactory answers have been found of till now. Can anyone help me ? Thanx in advance..
MY bower.json file looks like this :

```
    {
        "name": "client",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.2.6",
        "json3": "~3.2.6",
        "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
        "angular-resource": "1.2.6",
        "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6",
        "angular-route": "1.2.6",
        "angular-bootstrap": "~0.10.0",
        "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
        "underscore": "~1.6.0",
        "d3": "~3.4.1",
        "angular-touch": "~1.2.16",
        "deepcopy": "~0.3.2"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "1.2.6",
        "angular-scenario": "1.2.6"
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify your gruntfile a bit. Just write mingle to false in the jshint section and it will work.

Comment: Disable mingle will increase (unnecessarily) the javascript file size.

Comment: @cgcladera yeah but it will at least work which in case of mingle enabled doesn't work at all.

Comment: It works if you use injection array annotation [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). It also fixes other minifying issues.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this issue too. I found out the problem was caused by minify process because it renames functions' parameters, so the modal stopped working properly due to angular couldn't find the provider "a", for instance.

The fix is pretty easy. Just declare your modal controller using array instead of function.

**Example:**

```
var modal = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'partials/modal.html',
    controller: MyModalCtrl
});
var MyModalCtrl = [
    '$scope',
    '$modalInstance',
    function($scope, $modalInstance){
        ...
    }
];
```

Using array declaration syntax is highly recommended if you minify your code.

Hope this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I came to know the reason of the error. It's grunt minification task which is minifying the angular service variables and then angular is unable to find them. Just setting "mangle" to false in uglify solves the problem but it also increases the file size as compared to the normal file built with grunt when mangle is set to true(default).

But i would like to set mangle to true again. If somebody has already gone through issue an solved it then please post it below in the answers. Thank You.......

Comment: Check out the earlier response.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look in your file called "bower.json" and look if there is a line that goes something like

```
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0"
```

Also in your index.html you should take a look if there is

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited the question with my bower.json file and in my index.html i already have the path to .tpls file